# Large wooden mortar and pestle

Tags: equipment, thai-cuisine

Where in Australia can I get a large wooden mortar and pestle for making green papaya salad?

Comment: Hi Elizabeth, and welcome to the site! Could you link the recipe you're using, because I've never heard of a green papaya salad asking for a mortar and pestle. That said, is there a reason it should be made from wood? Nevertheless, I think your question will be closed since it's a sourcing question.

Comment: @Mien I haven't made it myself, but I think that you traditionally use the mortar to grind together some of the seasonings, and also to bruise/crush some of the vegetables to release juices. The possibly-westernized recipes I've found aren't too detailed about it, though.

Comment: Elizabeth, I think we'd be very interested in a question along the lines of "how can I make papaya salad *without* a mortar and pestle" (Martin even provided an answer along those lines already!) - if you'd be interested in anything like that please do edit your question. Otherwise as Mien said, this is probably going to stay closed - there are a ton of places you can buy things online, a ton of cooking stores, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I don't know where to get a big mortar and pestle in Australia, I would guess asian shops.

**However:** I have made thai green papaya salads with and without a mortar. The mortar helps release and combine the juices and flavors. However, if you don't have one there is no reason to rush off and buy one ... you can blitz nuts, garlic (or use garlic press) and chillies in a food processor quickly if you want really small peaces, and the rest of ingredients (the shredded veggies) you can just knead a well with your hands/fists in a bowl ... and it works pretty well to get really nice delicious salad.

[I have seen people also using a rolling pin or a jar to smash the ingredients placed in a ziplock bag.](http://shesimmers.com/2010/06/som-tam-tutorial-how-to-make-thai-green.html)

Bon appetit!